# How to set TTL in php based app for DynamoDB programmatically

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I need to set time to live programmatically for a table in DynamoDB via AWS PHP SDK. Is it possible? 
if it is possible then how?
my table name is "tablename1" and it contains 
`UUID, name, score, played on(DateTime)`. 
I need to remove the data every one hour. 
for example,  now the time 8pm then remove all item which added up to 6pm.
likewise now 9pm then remove all item which added up to 7pm.

Comment: The most clean approach is to use Scheduled Lambda for the job. However Lambda doesn't support php at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link here for more information:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#updatetimetolive

```
$result = $client->updateTimeToLive([
    'TableName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'TimeToLiveSpecification' => [ // REQUIRED
        'AttributeName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
        'Enabled' => true || false, // REQUIRED
    ],
]);
```